# Appcrash when i try to add QTabWidget with a button

Tags: c++, qt

i just started  learning Qt few days ago, and i have a problem that i can't solve.

First there is the files :

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "test.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
test w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

class test : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT


  public:
     test();
     ~test();
  private slots:
     void addT();


  private :

     QTabWidget *tab;
     QPushButton *b,*c;


};

#endif // TEST_H
```

and test.cpp

```
 #include "test.h"

 test::test()
 {
     QTabWidget *tab = new QTabWidget(this);
      QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("Add",this);

     tab->addTab(b,"test");
     QObject::connect(b,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(addT()));
 }

  test::~test()
 {

 }

 void test::addT()
 {
      QPushButton *c= new QPushButton("Add",this);
      tab->addTab(c,"test");
 }
```

the program starts normally but when i push the button to add a new Tab it crashes

Please Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you are not assigning to the QTabWidget and QPushButton instanced declared in your header, but are creating two new instances (with the same name) that will be gone at the end of the scope. The tab instance is still a nullptr and when trying to derefence it in addT, your program will crash. You need to assign to the variables declared in test.h like this:

`test::test() : tab(new QTabWidget(this), b(new QPushButton("Add", this) {
    ...
 }`

Comment: THANK you very very much it worked !! So every variable i declare in .h file must appear in the beginning of the fonction ,Right?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter, where the declared variable is initialized. You just need to make sure not to use something like QTabWidget *tab = new QTabWidget(this); like in your example, while wanting to reference the tab variable declared in your header, because it will create a new >separate< instance.